# Base of a directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

We call the base B of a directed graph *G(V, E)* a minimal subset of vertices, such that any vertex in *V/B* can be reached from some vertex in B.

Prove that no two vertices in B are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two vertices $v_1,v_2\in B$ are connected, then either $v_1$ can be reached from $v_2$ or $v_2$ can be reached from $v_1$, depending on the direction of the edge. Without loss of generality say $v_2$ can be reached from $v_1$. Then any vertex that can be reached from $v_2$ can also be reached from $v_1$, so $B\setminus\{v_2\}$ is still a base of the graph. This contradicts the minimality of $B$, so no two vertices in $B$ can be connected.